# Tag synonyms for [strings] and [parser]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I would like to propose the following tag synonyms:

- [strings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings) (6) -> [string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) (6)
- [parser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parser) (4) -> [parsing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) (5)

Also, I'm not sure that the [improvement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/improvement) (4) and [readability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readability) (19) tags adds anything useful to a site about code reviews, but may be persuaded otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've merged and synonymed the mentioned tags. I've also removed the improvement tag as it indeed seems to be superfluous.

I've kept the readbility tag though because it's marginally useful (it tells us that the asker is primarily looking for improvements in the area of readability as opposed to e.g. performance or robustness) and I also didn't want to bump 19 questions just to remove the tag.

Comment: I accept your reasoning regarding the "readability" tag. Thanks for for your efforts regarding the rest.

Comment: Also, just so you're aware - apparently merging tags [doesn't bump questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page/29395#29395).

Comment: @Michael: Yes, but you can't use the merge tool to remove a tag. So unless I missed something there's no way to remove a tag without bumping the questions.